# How to un-pixelate pixelated regions in films?

Tags: image-processing

Everybody knows the effect of pixelated objects (e.g. faces) on TV. Is there a way - and which mathematical method lies behind it - to un-pixelate the region? Beware: I am not talking about smoothing it out (unblur) image by image - but about using the information of a whole sequence of pixelated pictures where the object which is pixelated naturally changes the location within the overall pixelated region. I guess it must be some kind of "un-averaging over time" (e.g. differentiation over time comes into mind).

Has anybody tackled this problem yet? Are there references, demos, software...?

Thank you.

Comment: Offtopic      ?

Comment: @unknowngoogle: No, I don't think so because the underlying math should not be trivial.

Comment: It sounds like a question in applied maths, not a research level question in maths. 
Could you give your mathematical definition of "pixelated object", "region", "image", "smoothing out"... ?

Comment: Sounds extremely hard to do. To do that, you should first obtain some information on how the pixelated object moves in successive frame. And that is a difficult problem in itself, even on plain un-pixelated images.

Comment: I agree that it must be extremely hard to do, but I think it is also an extremely interesting research effort!

Comment: @unknowngogle: Yes, it does sound like a question in applied math, doesn't it? I don't think it makes it not research-level or unsuitable for MO, though. 

Comment: Ok, so it's just the case that I'm not aware of the maths behind pixelating etc [and I've just noticed that there indeed exists a tag called "image processing"]. I raised the doubt because I've seen questions on computer science been closed.

Comment: You might also try the astronomy literature --- all the time they deal with point sources being pixelated. It's been a long time since I was an astronomer, so I don't have any references for you, sadly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a problem that has been addressed by the computer vision community in the past few years. You may want to look into upsampling and super-resolution techniques as well as vectorization methods. Here is a recent paper on the topic in ICCV 2009 which gives a good summary of the recent efforts in this field: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html

Comment: This is extremely helpful - now I have the keywords for finding out more -  obviously there is some high-level research going here - Thank you!